# Best way to handle custom configuration variables in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was wondering what is the best way to handle custom configuration in a large Rails up. At the moment we are using the YAML method as defined in [RailsCast #85](http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file). I like this because it lets you share defaults between environments (most stuff for us is the same in development and test), however we are duplicating a lot of code, and setting a global doesn't seem too nice.

We currently use this to store configuration for:

- Redis (for caching and Sidekiq - two different configurations)
- Paypal
- Credit card payments (with another provider)
- SMS gateway
- Statsd
- Internal APIs

That Railscast is nearly six years old, is there a nicer way to do this now?

(N.b. I see that this type of question has been asked a lot before, but all of the answers I have seen talk about fairly simple one of two variable configuration, where as ours is quite big!)

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the [SimpleConfig gem](https://github.com/lukeredpath/simpleconfig) for the last 4 years. It's a lightweight and flexible solution, and it supports per-environment overrides and defaults.

*Disclaimer: I'm also a contributor to the gem.*